# How to send struct array as parameter instead of sending members as arrays for sorting algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

So i'm trying to refine my sorting algorithm code. Basically i have a struct which has two members, both an array. I only need to sort the first member but the second member is tied to it so what i did is i sorted by the first member and basically arrange the second member by how the first member was arranged.

```
void selection::selectionSort(int a[], int b[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        int iMin = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (a[j] < a[iMin])
                iMin = j;
        }
        swap(a[i], a[iMin]);
        swap(b[i], b[iMin]); 
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << ' ';
        cout << b[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Here is one of my sorting algorithm, with a being the first member needed to be sorted and b is the other member.
Here is the class

```
struct classes
{
    int course[10];
    int section[10];
}
```

I think this is not an efficient way or i might run into trouble sooner or later with other sorting algorithms so i'm wondering if there is a way in which i can send an array of struct object.

Comment: Why did you choose a struct of two arrays, instead of an array of structs with two elements?

Comment: That is what I'm trying to do but don't know how to send it as an argument or how to set up the parameters.